# Error: Could not find or load main class jar when packaging via maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have written a Spring boot application.
I am running `mvn clean install` on the pom.xml. This generates a .jar file in my target folder but when running `java -jar fb-0.0.1-snapshot.jar` on the jar file, I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar
```

I pretty much have a simple springboot application.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) on how to package a jar using maven but still no luck. This is part of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.bob.fb.MainApplication
                        </mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My main class does reside in that package: `com.bob.fb`.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the following: "[If `-jar` is specified, then its argument is the name of the JAR file containing class and resource files for the application. The startup class must be indicated by the `Main-Class` manifest header in its manifest file.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#description)"?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Thanks for pointing that out... turns out I hada typo in the command which drove me nuts and thus creating this question! I was writing `java jar XXX` instead of `java -jar XXX`

Answer (score -1):

Delete this pom.xml and try to rewrite all the dependencies and re-run the editor. This will reload all the dependencies again. Sometimes maven doesn't load all the dependencies.

Comment: Didn't you see the OPs last comment to the Q?